# Onchange missing AJAX validation with django

Tags: django, ajax, sqlite

I've been trying to validate the title field using AJAX.(If the title exist in the table display the error "Title already exists"). I looked at many examples, but some are old and do not work, while others I do not understand.Below is the code, please help with the implementation.
Here is my code:-

models.py

```
class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class postForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'title',
            'description'
        )
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'title', 'required': True,}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'description', 'required': True})
        }
```

views.py

```
def validate_title(request):
    title = request.GET.get('title', None)
    data = {
        'is_taken': Post.objects.filter(title=title).exists()
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)


class postClass(CreateView):
    template_name = 'create_post.html'
    form_class = postForm

    def create_post(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        response_data = {}
        form = postForm()
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            description = request.POST.get('description')

            response_data['title'] = title
            response_data['description'] = description

            Post.objects.create(
                title=title,
                description=description,
            )
            return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('create/', postClass.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('validate_title', views.validate_title, name='validate_title'),
]
```

create_post.html

```
<body>
<form method="POST" id="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 400px;margin-top: 50px">
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" style="margin-left: 20px" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    {% for i in posts %}
        <label>{{ i.title }}</label>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('submit', '#post-form', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "create" %}',
                data: {
                    title: $('#title').val(),
                    description: $('#description').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                    action: 'post'
                },
            });
        });
    });

</script>
<script>
    $("#title").change(function () {
        var title = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url "validate_title" %}',
            data: {
                title: $('#title').val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.is_taken) {
                    alert("Title already exists.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

I've tried many method but none of them is working . can someone help

Comment: Is thing code working?

Comment: Yes ofcourse..!

Comment: so what do want to do with this more?

Comment: Now I want to update the page with latest values

Comment: of which column value you want to upadte?

Comment: title, and the values displayed in the template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221406/discussion-between-sarath-chandran-and-surya-pratap-rana).